# how to export object from maya into opengl application

Tags: object, opengl, import, maya

Im learning openGL, basically ive created an object in Maya, im wondering how i go about exporting it, and loading it into my application ive created (it is simply a plain square room with different coloured walls at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL doesn't have the concept of models. You'll have to write your own model loader, or use one that's already out there. If you opt for writing your own, you should probably export as .obj, that's a fairly simple text based format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i now have an object loaded into my application, however it appears there is a problem with my normals... i exported from maya as obj (textures dont work), imported into blender, exported again and the textures work...

Comment: Be sure you know which coordinate system and handedness you're using in your own code. Maya is left-handed Y-up; OGL is right-handed (see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124041/is-opengl-coordinate-system-left-handed-or-right-handed).  The handedness difference is probably why your normals are reversed.