# How to translate and scale objects in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I can use the below code to scale and translate a square using OpenGLES. But I'm not sure how to calculate the translation and scale factors. For example using the below picture of the OpenGL coordinate system and `Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, .5f, 0, 0);` I would expect the square to be drawn halfway to the right of the screen, but instead it's drawn halfway to the left from the center. However `Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, .5f, 0);` does translate the square halfway up the screen from the center.

How would I translate and scale in order to programmatically draw `N` squares side by side horizontally filling the top of the screen?

[image: OpenGLES coordinate system]

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    // Draw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Translate by some amount
    // Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, ?, ?, 0);

    // Scale by some amount
    // Matrix.scaleM(mViewMatrix, 0, ?, ?, 1);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    // Draw square
    mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}
```

Comment: In eye space, +Z moves towards the viewer. You have eyeZ as -3 so you are actually on the other side of the viewing plane looking back. That is why your x axis translation appears to move in the wrong direction but the y translation does not. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124041/is-opengl-coordinate-system-left-handed-or-right-handed. Yes, it can be somewhat confusing...

Comment: Ahh, that explains that part of the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need translate and scale to fill up a row of squares. To get rows of squares programmatically in openGL ES I would just make a bunch of squares initialized where you want them. An edited snippet from one of my projects went something like this:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config){
   GLES20.glClearColor(bgr, bgg, bgb, bga);
   float z=0.0f;
   float y=0.0f;
   for(float i=(-worldwidth);i<worldwidth;i+=(cellwidth)){
      square=new Square(i,y,z);     
      cellvec.addElement(square);
   }
}
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    for(int i=0;i<cellvec.size();i++){
        cellvec.elementAt(i).draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }
}
```

I am not entirely sure if something like this is what your looking for but it it seems to get the result of a row of squares like you wanted.