# Ended up with left handed coordinate system OpenGL but I need right handed

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, coordinate-systems, perspectivecamera

So I started to make my own engine, and got my Z axis pointing away from my camera. I don't know why it happened, I followed [this tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) pretty much.

I'll post my **persprojection** and **view** calculations of my camera, please comment what other code should I post, and I'll update my post.

**PersProjection**

```
void Camera::setPerspective(float width, float height, float nearZ, float farZ, float angleDeg) {
perspectiveTrans.toZero();

float ar = width / height;

angleDeg = Math3D::ToRadian(angleDeg);

perspectiveTrans(0, 0) = 1.0f / (ar * tanf(angleDeg / 2.0f));
perspectiveTrans(1, 1) = 1.0f / tanf(angleDeg / 2.0f);
perspectiveTrans(2, 2) = (-nearZ - farZ) / (nearZ - farZ);
perspectiveTrans(2, 3) = (2.0f * farZ * nearZ) / (nearZ - farZ);
perspectiveTrans(3, 2) = 1.0f;
}
```

**View** and **Projection** calculations

```
Matrix4x4f Camera::getViewProjection() {
Matrix4x4f cameraRotationTrans(MatrixType::IDENTITY);

Vector3f N = target;
N.normalize();
Vector3f U = up;
U.normalize();
U = U.cross(target);
Vector3f V = N.cross(U);

cameraRotationTrans.setRow(0, Vector4f(U, 0));
cameraRotationTrans.setRow(1, Vector4f(V, 0));
cameraRotationTrans.setRow(2, Vector4f(N, 1));

Matrix4x4f cameraTranslationTrans(MatrixType::IDENTITY);
cameraTranslationTrans.setCol(3, Vector4f(-position, 1));

return perspectiveTrans * cameraRotationTrans * cameraTranslationTrans;
}
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124041/is-opengl-coordinate-system-left-handed-or-right-handed

Comment: Typically you'd put that operation in the modelview matrix, as a scaling component along Z with the -1 factor.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a minus sign in this expression:

```
perspectiveTrans(2, 3) = (2.0f * nearZ * farZ) / -(nearZ - farZ);
```

If you look up the corresponding matrix elements in the documentation for [`glFrustum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373537(v=vs.85).aspx), this matrix element is:

```
- (2 * far * near / (far - near)
```

In your notation, that is:

```
perspectiveTrans(2, 3) = (-2.0f * nearZ * farZ) / -(nearZ - farZ);
```

Comment: Before posting I was playing with the minus signs and of course I've posted a wrong code, thanks for pointing out the problem anyways. I've updated my code according to [this formula](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial12/12_11.png), (the whole article is [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial12/tutorial12.html)). Still no luck. Any suggestions what part of my code should I check?

Comment: It's not really the idea of this site that you change your question in a way that invalidates answers that were already posted. In any case, the matrix you linked is not the projection matrix that is typically used with OpenGL. That's why your coordinate system is left-handed. Just use the one I linked, and it will work.

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. Could you post an answer about your formula, so I can accept it?