# Migrate from fixed-function to GLSL OpenGL: How should I modify my view (lookAt) matrix and perspection matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to migrate my OpenGL rendering pipeline from fixed-point to modern OpenGL. My fixed-point 3D pipeline works well for years. Now when I switch to GLSL, the final projection and object orientation looks like "totally mirrored or swapped". I have excluded all other reasons (like fail to set matrix uniforms, etc.) since I can see the 3D scene is rendered from time to time by randomly dragging my mouse to pan the camera. So the question is narrowed down to the following:

- The function that generates view matrix (my function getViewMat(pos, lookat, upaxis))
- The function that generates perspective projection matrix (my function getPerspectiveMat(fov, aspect, nearZ, farZ))

Since these two functions generate correct view / projection matrix before for fixed-point pipeline, now I'm wondering whether / how I can modify them to make the generated matrices work for shader pipeline?

There are few [stack overflow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124041/is-opengl-coordinate-system-left-handed-or-right-handed/10264334#10264334) suggests that for shader pipeline, we need to manually flip Z value for projection matrix, but how about the view matrix? Many thanks for any suggestions.

**Update:** 
Soure code

```
/*
    Matrix4f has class members "float m00, m01, m02, m03, m10, m11, ..., m33" representing
    a row-dominant 4x4 matrix, when passed to GLSL, I have remembered to transpose them
*/
void Matrix4f::_getPerspectiveByFov(float fov, float aspectRatio, float nearZ, float farZ, int matrixType)
{
    float halfFov   = MathUtil::degToRad(fov) * 0.5f;
    float width, height;
    //We use the small side out of width and height as the base size, then calculate the other side by aspect ratio.
    float _tanFOV = (float)tan(halfFov);
    if(aspectRatio < 1.f)//width is smaller
    {
        width   = 2.f * nearZ * _tanFOV;
        height  = width / aspectRatio;
    }
    else    //height is smaller
    {
        height  = 2.f * nearZ * _tanFOV;
        width   = height * aspectRatio;
    }

    /*
    Formula from OpenGL reference, see function "glFrustum".
        |w      0       0       0|
        |0      h       0       0|
        |0      0       -C      D|
        |0      0       1       0|

    w = 2.f * nearZ / width
    h = 2.f * nearZ / height
    C = -(farZ + nearZ) / (farZ - nearZ)
    D = -2.f * farZ * nearZ / (farZ - nearZ);
    */
    float w = 2.f * nearZ / width;  // Is equal to: [ 1.f / tan(fov*0.5f) ]
    float h = 2.f * nearZ / height; // Is equal to: [ 1.f / tan(fov*0.5f) / aspectRatio ]
    float C = -(farZ + nearZ) / (farZ - nearZ);
    float D = -2.f * farZ * nearZ / (farZ - nearZ);

    //-----------------------
    m00 = w;
    m01 = 0.f;
    m02 = 0.f;
    m03 = 0.f;

    m10 = 0.f;
    m11 = h;
    m12 = 0.f;
    m13 = 0.f;

    m20 = 0.f;
    m21 = 0.f;
    m22 = -C;
    m23 = D;

    m30 = 0.f;
    m31 = 0.f;
    m32 = 1.f;
    m33 = 0.f;
}

void Matrix4f::_getLookAt(Vector3f& pos, Vector3f& lookat, Vector3f& upAxis)
{
    //Note _forward, _right, _up are working vector of type Vector3f

    _up.set(upAxis);
    _forward.sub(lookat, pos);
    _forward.normalize();
    _right.cross(_up, _forward);
    _right.normalize();
    _up.cross(_forward, _right);
    _up.normalize();

    m00 = _right.x;
    m10 = _right.y;
    m20 = _right.z;

    m01 = _up.x;
    m11 = _up.y;
    m21 = _up.z;

    m02 = _forward.x;
    m12 = _forward.y;
    m22 = _forward.z;

    // Locate the camera
    m03 = pos.x;
    m13 = pos.y;
    m23 = pos.z;

    m30 = 0.f;
    m31 = 0.f;
    m32 = 0.f;

    m33 = 1.f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, It's a little hard to add all source code, I'll try to modify my question.

Comment: 1. My 4x4 matrices are row-dominant, I have transposed them when sending to shader (if I forgot, the rendering result is black-screen) 2. when I multiply matrix in shader, I did this: mat4 mat_vm = mat_view * mat_model; mat4 mat_pvm = mat_proj * mat_vm;

Comment: By following other posts suggestions, after I calculate the projection matrix, I negate z values: m02*-1, -m12*-1, -m22*-1, m32*-1, so just like what you suggested. But I start seeing black-screen until I randomely negate some values in view matrix to make it appear. But I do not know the correct way to adjust view matrix?

Comment: without seeing what are you doing in Vertex shader we can only guess ...

Answer (score 1):

without seeing what are you doing in **Vertex shader** we can only guess. However You can use the same matrices in new OpenGL as in the old one. The only matrix you probably do not have is the `gluPerspective` so you can implement it your self (in case you  do not have glu.h anymore). I do it like this:

```
void glPerspective(double fovy,double aspect,double zNear,double zFar)
    {
    double per[16],f;
    for (int i=0;i<16;i++) per[i]=0.0;
    // original gluProjection
//  f=divide(1.0,tan(0.5*fovy*deg))
//  per[ 0]=f/aspect;
//  per[ 5]=f;
    // corrected gluProjection
    f=divide(1.0,tan(0.5*fovy*deg*aspect));
    per[ 0]=f;
    per[ 5]=f*aspect;
    // z range
    per[10]=divide(zFar+zNear,zNear-zFar);
    per[11]=-1.0;
    per[14]=divide(2.0*zFar*zNear,zNear-zFar);
    glLoadMatrixd(per);
//  zNear=divide(-per[11],per[10]);     // get znear from perspective projection matrix
    }
```

It more or less mimics `gluPerspective` but it has repaired the inaccurate `tan` which caused problems when stacking up more frustrums together. The commented lines show how to compute original `gluPerspective` (also with `tan` repaired) and last comment shows how to get `znear` from matrix (for ray tracers)

Of coarse instead of `glLoadMatrixd(per);` you use the `per` as you need ... (like send as `uniform`)

Now to implement lookat you just construct the matrix your self. See:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

So you simply compute the `X,Y,Z` vectors and `O` origin position

```
Z = -forward
X = +right
Y = +up
O = +camera_position - znear
```

and feed them into your matrix at desired locations...

Now if your `lookat` is position of target object than

```
Z = normalize(camera_position-lookat)
Y = up
X = cross(Y,Z)
```

Not sure if `X` should be + or - just try and if scene is mirrored then negate it.

Comment: Although I have fixed my problem before I saw your answer, your info is very useful, thanks! My problem is that the pos-lookat-axis matrix generated in my lookAt() function is camera's world transformation matrix, I should use its inverse matrix to pass in the vertex shader as the "view" matrix.